# Why risk-free interest is needed for Margrabe's Formula?

Tags: options, quantlib, pricing, margrabes-formula

The source code for Margarble's formula in QuantLib is [here](https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib/blob/2a5c086844775b6c1b986df2a5631d2ba3b1e6a4/QuantLib/ql/experimental/exoticoptions/analyticeuropeanmargrabeengine.cpp). The implementation requires a forward price be computed:

```
    Real forward1 = process1_->stateVariable()->value() *
        dividendDiscount1 / riskFreeDiscount;
    Real forward2 = process2_->stateVariable()->value() *
        dividendDiscount2 / riskFreeDiscount;
```

Why do we have to calculate the forward price? Margrable's formula explicity states that risk-free interest rate is not assumed because we can price the option under a stock measure. The formula in the original paper and wikipedia doesn't require it.

```
    Real d1 = (std::log((quantity1*forward1)/(quantity2*forward2))
               + 0.5*variance) / stdDev;
```

If one of the dividends is zero, we would get into a situation of log(0). Where do the extra terms that not shown come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need the risk-free rate, it's just the way it's been implemented. It will cancel out when you take the ratio of the forwards.